# nginx proxy for Javascript WebSocket client

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket, proxy

I have nginx running on localhost serving static html/css/js files.  It proxies to a remote server for the required RESTful db services.  I need to also setup nginx to proxy to a remote websocket server but failing miserably with all attempts.

The Javascript client works if I hardcode the websocket server url like this:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://50.29.123.83:9030/something/socket");
```

Obviously, not a optimal solution and I should be able to use location.host and a proxy to get to the same location.   I configured nginx with the following:

```
http {
  ...
  upstream websocket {
    server 50.29.123.83:9030;
    }
}

sever {
  ...
  location /the_socket/ {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

Then updated the client code to:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/the_socket/something/socket");
```

This fails with the following error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/the_socket/something/socket'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   404

What am I doing wrong?

- ip & port numbers changed to protect the innocent

Comment: It looks like `location.host` is referencing `localhost` which is probably pointing to the local nginx instance, but if they are the same thing, then there's also the issue that `location.host` is also not including the port in the url

Comment: location.host is referencing localhost where the local nginx is running.  the port is specified in the proxy_pass via the upstream server declaration.

Comment: You will be accessing the remote server with `/the_socket/something/socket`, as you have not attempted to remove the prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proxy statement will pass the URI to the upstream server unmodified. That is the text `/the_socket` will still be attached to the beginning of the URI.

If you want `proxy_pass` to modify the URI and remove the `location` value - you should add a URI to the `proxy_pass` statement. For example:

```
location /the_socket/ {
    proxy_pass http://websocket/;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.